# How to improve this list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, list, list-comprehension

I need to evaluate the following list comprehension:

```
[r for r in listOfList if
  1 not in [lst[i] for i in r] and
  0 in     [lst[i] for i in r]
]
```

That is, I need to get as result a list of lists (of numbers), where each of them has no element equal to 1, but at least one element equal to 0.
As you can see there is the repetition of `[lst[i] for i in r]`.
Is there a way to improve the evaluation of my list comprehension?

Examples:

```
listOfList = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], 
[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

lst = [0, 1, None, None, None, 1, None, None, 0]
```

Comment: What exactly are you checking for? Why do you have a variable named `list`, and what is (or could be) in it? Only ever zeroes and ones?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `list` can be filled with 1, 0 and None values.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of `listOfList` and `list` (don't name it that, it shadows the built-in)?

Comment: In essence your `r` is a set of indices into `list` then, and you need to know which of the index lists contain no `1` values but do have `0` values.

Comment: You should never use `list` as a variable name; it masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested loop to compute the sub-set from `lst` first, *or* you can use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to use a generator expression and limit the number of iterations:

Using a nested list loop:

```
[r for r in listOfList 
   for indexed in ({lst[i] for i in r},)
   if 1 not in indexed and 0 in indexed]
```

I also changed the sub-set from `lst` to a set to make use of faster constant time membership tests.

Using `any()`:

```
[r for r in listOfList 
   if not any(lst[i] == 1 for i in r) and
      any(lst[i] == 0 for i in r)]
```

`any()` will stop iterating over the generator the moment an expression that evaluates to `True` is encountered.

Comment: Is there any performance/memory improvement using the former rather than the latter? Please replace your 0 with 1 (and vice versa) in the "any" case.

Comment: @Nick: that depends on how big the subsets are going to be, and on the distribution and probability of the `0` and `1` values. Creating a large set with thousands of elements might be more expensive than the `any()` tests if you can determine quite quickly that a `1` or `0` is present merely by looking at the first few elements, for example.